# Display message on form submit instead of redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a sign-up form that is fairly basic. I am trying to display a success message (on-page, in a pop-up, in an alert... I have no preference) VS. redirecting to the page that the form is posting to (which is what is currently happening).

```
<form action="path/to/form/main/index.php" method="post">
<p>
<input name="contact[first_name]" placeholder="Your First Name" type="text">
<input name="contact[email]" placeholder="youremail@address.com" type="text">
<input class="btn btn-success btn-large" value="Sign Me Up" type="submit">
</p>
<input name="action" value="ext_addcontact" type="hidden">
<input name="selectedgroupname" value="Website Opt-Ins" type="hidden">
<input name="groupownerid" value="[p:pid]" type="hidden">
</form>
```

[p:pid] is a variable tag for the system which populates server-side.
Example: http://aia.dmplocal.com/sites/52/index.html
Sorry for any idiocy here - I'm very new to JS/AJAX. Thanks

EDIT: I have no control over the location that the form is posting to (index.php).

Comment: The easiest way would be to add a redirect to your PHP code. After saving the form data (which I assume happens in index.php), you could add a line like: `header('Location: my_success_page.php');`

Comment: Hi Matt - I'd love to, but I don't have access to edit index.php. It pretty much needs to be a solution that I can achieve within the page (which I have complete control over)

Comment: @MattBrowne that is still a redirect, that is not what OP wants.

Comment: Use AJAX to submit it.

Comment: @putvande - I'm open to it. What is my structure/format? Completely new territory

Comment: You can start [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: could you post the content of action="path/to/form/main/index.php". The index.php ?

Comment: @putvande - I'll see if I can figure it out.

Comment: @pracede - if the solution involves any sort of editing to the index.php I can't do it. Needs to be before the redirect.

Comment: @user3366357 [This](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) is a pretty cool jQuery plugin for AJAXing forms. Really simple to setup and use. I've used it dozens of times...

Comment: @user3366357 War10ck exposed a excellent plugin so you can start

Comment: @user3366357 Glad to hear it buddy. I've moved it to an answer below and added a small subset of startup code that may help you out. Good luck and happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#json) by Malsup would be an excellent place to start. It is very easy to setup and use. I've used it several times myself.

This should get you started:

```
$(function () {
    $('form').ajaxForm({
        // Use this property to specify how your data will
        // look when it's returned (i.e. JSON, XML, HTML,
        // etc). If you aren't returning any data, you can
        // omit this property.
        dataType: ...,
        success: function (res) {
            // Do something in here on success. Depending on your
            // requirements you may or may not have a result
            // returned to you.
        },
        error: function (res) {
            // Do something in here on error. You should always
            // have an error object passed to you that details
            // the error and possibly any returned error text.
        }
    });
});
```

For a complete list of options available to you, please see [this](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object) API reference page.

Comment: i will not have time to implement this until later this afternoon, but it looks so idiot proof (read:me-proof) that I see no reason it will not work exactly as described. Thanks for helping me dip my toe into new waters!